# In .NET regular expressions, how do I look for a match that is not at the end of the string?

Tags: .net, regex

The rest of the match does not make any difference. It's the "is not at the end of the string" part I need.

A very simple question, I'm sure, but I'm very "green" when it comes to regular expressions. I'm thinking maybe negative look ahead, but not sure the syntax on this.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the source code for what you have so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes a negative lookahead would work here:

```
@"your_regex(?!$)"
```

Another alternative is just to match any character using `.` after the part you want to capture:

```
@"(your_regex)."
```

Comment: `$` could also mean "end of the line"; `\z` would be a bit safer because it always means "end of the string", regardless of currently set regex options.

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker: True. If he has multiline strings the second alternative would also need modifying - `.` doesn't match newline by default. The flag `RegexOptions.Singleline` fixes that.

Comment: Thanks, guys. The "(?!$)" or "(?!\z)" was the correct syntax. Both work great.

Answer (score 1):

Just look for your matchText and insist that it has one or more characters after it before the end.

```
var re = new Regex("(matchText).+$");
```